Inductive from CoInductive?
It is possible to represent CoInductive using parts that are Inductive.
As a simple example,
CoInductive stream A :=
| SCons : A -> stream A -> stream A
. 
Arguments SCons {A}.

CoInductive streq {A} : stream A -> stream A -> Prop :=
| SRefl : forall h ta tb, streq ta tb -> streq (SCons h ta) (SCons h tb)
.

Definition shead {A} (s : stream A) := match s with
| SCons h _ => h
end.
    
Definition stail {A} (s : stream A) := match s with
| SCons _ t => t
end.

Definition stream_unfold {A} (s : stream A) : s = SCons (shead s) (stail s).
  destruct s; apply eq_refl.
Defined.

Definition stream_idx {A} := fix loop (s : stream A) n := match n with
| 0 => shead s  
| S n0 => loop (stail s) n0
end.

Definition stream_from_fn {A} :=
  cofix s (f : nat -> A) := SCons (f 0) (s (fun n => f (S n))).

Definition fneq {A B} (f g : A -> B) := forall a, f a = g a.

Theorem stream_from_fn_from_stream {A} (s : stream A) : streq s (stream_from_fn (stream_idx s)).
  revert s; cofix seq; intros.
  destruct s.
  rewrite (stream_unfold (stream_from_fn _)).
  apply SRefl, seq.
Qed.
  
Theorem fn_from_stream_from_fn {A} (f : nat -> A) : fneq f (stream_idx (stream_from_fn f)).
  intros n; revert f; induction n; intros; [ apply eq_refl | ].
  apply (IHn (fun n => f (S n))).
Qed.

So, we can convert between nat -> A and stream A and they are isomorphic.
In a sense, we are representing the CoInductive with a function based on
the Inductive nat.
My question is: Is the reverse possible?  Can an Inductive be built
using CoInductive?  For example, imagine you had Coq only with
the CoInductive statement, but not Inductive statement, nor did you
do the same by making equivalent Axioms.  How far could you build?

Try asking in proofassistants.stackexchange.com

Thanks.  Forwarded to https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/3921/
